# On window scroll change a component style in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

On window scroll how can I capture the scroll values and change the position of one of the components in the DOM in Angular 2?
I found @HostListener can be used, but it doesn't work for me, I am using the following code:

```
   import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-submenu',
  templateUrl: './submenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./submenu.component.scss'],
  inputs : ['menuItems']
})
export class SubmenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public menuItems;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    @HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event){
      console.log($event);
      console.log("scrolling");
    } 
}
```

What is the best way to capture the dom events like a scroll, resize...etc in Angular 2?

Comment: Is it the same element that has the listener?

Comment: Yes it is in the same component

Comment: No, I am still unable to capture the scroll events..:(, can you share some reference code/project?

Comment: Test the 'mousewheel' event, do you have any other hostlisteners in the app?  the element having the listener has it overflow:scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You are already using a good way: @Hostlistener. To make it work, better to write a directive in which add the listener.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[scroll]' })
export class TrackScrollDirective {

   constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
   }
   @HostListener('document:scroll', []){
   onScroll(): void {
     this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('style','position:fixed')
   }
}
```

Make sure the element has `overflow:scroll`

Comment: According to my code It has to log the event in the console, which is not triggering, any guess why it is not triggering the scroll event?

Comment: Are you on a touch screen?

Comment: No, I am not using touch screen.

Comment: Post the whole code of to see how you implement it. Otherwise have you tested mine?

Comment: It's better to do it in a directive instead of directly putting in the component class. And I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Vega Thanks for your help, I tried with your suggestions and finally it is working by replacing **document by body** , following is my workable code :

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[scroll]' })
export class TrackScrollDirective {

   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
   }

   @HostListener('body:scroll', ['$event'])
   onScrollEvent($event){
     this.elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('style','top:500px');
   }
}
```

Thanks again for you help.